# Is there any method in as3 that flash can write file's last modified date

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any method in as3 that flash can write file's last modified date.

Its stand alone flash application which had external swf loading. I want to check the last modified date of the swf during the loading.
please suggest any possible methods.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In AIR, there is `File` class with `modificationDate` property. But in plain AS3, there's no file concept at all. If you loading swf with Loader, you only get data, but **not** the attributes of file (and file might not exist at all if loading something by URL.)